# Sass: Return list values with unique characters only

Tags: sass

Can anyone provide a function to return values from a list only if they do not contain duplicate characters ?

For example, Lets say that I have list with values as `$list: (aa, bb, cd, ef);`

Expected output:

> (cd, ef);

This is the code I have got so far. It does not solve my issue at all, but after multiple trials, this is all I could get.

```
@function dupChars($list, $separator: comma) {

  $result: null;
  $temp: null;

  @each $item in $list {

    @for $i from 1 through str-length($item) {

      @if not index($temp, str-slice($item, $i, $i)) {

        $temp: append($temp, #{str-slice($item, $i, $i)}, $separator);
      }
    }
  }

  $result: append($result, $temp, $separator);

  @return $result;
}

$list: (aa, bb, cd, ef);

/* #{dupChars($list)} */
```

Obtained output:

> a, b, c, d, e, f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try to resolve this, I found that a way could be check for every items how many same singole letter there are in it (using a double `@for` loop).

For example, imagine to have this list: `abc`. If the result is 3 (the length of my item) I know that every letter is only once in that item, then there is no duplicates (3 = 3).

```
a -- a // 1
a -- b
a -- c
b -- a
b -- b // 2
b -- c
c -- a
c -- b
c -- c // 3
```

Another example. Now our list is `aab`. The result is bigger than the length of my item so we have duplicates (5 > 3)

```
a -- a // 1
a -- a // 2
a -- b 
a -- a // 3
a -- a // 4
a -- b
b -- a
b -- a
b -- b // 5
```

So when the number is bigger than my item's length, I don't append that `$temp` to my `$result`

The code:

```
@function dupChars($list, $separator: comma) {
    $result: null;
    $temp: null;

    @each $item in $list {
        $var: 0;
        @for $i from 1 through length($item) {

            @for $j from 1 through (str-length($item)) {

                @for $k from 1 through (str-length($item)) {
                    //@debug str-slice($item, $j, $j) + "---" + str-slice($item, $k, $k) ;

                    @if (str-slice($item, $j, $j) == str-slice($item, $k, $k)) {
                        $var: $var + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        @if($var <= str-length($item)){
          $temp: append($temp, #{$item}, $separator);
        }
    }

    $result: append($result, $temp, $separator);

    @return $result;
}

$lista: (aa, bb, cd, ef);

div{content: dupChars($lista)};
```

The output:

```
div {
  content: cd, ef;
}
```

Comment: That's quite a simple and clear solution. Worked out great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. It was very interesting to find a solution using sass. :-)

Comment: This whole issue was quite easy to solve using JS but when it came to Sass It turned a bit confusing with all the workarounds.

Comment: Yeah! Without `@break` or something like that to stop the loop I had to find a workaround. I found an article about this: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/378

Comment: True, Sass still needs to evolve a lot but with what it's capable, I tried making it a recursive function, But It started looking for common characters in all values in the list and treated each of them as duplicates. For example: if `$list: aa, ab, bb, cd` only `cd` would be an output as the rest have common characters.

Comment: Mmh.. that's an interesting new question. You need to find ways to keep track of all duplicate characters...